# spark ClassNotFoundException error for performing kmeans

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to submit a spark job for using spark KMeans. I am packaging the scala file correctly, but when I want to submit the job I always have the ClassNotFoundException.
Here is my sbt fille:

name:="sparkKmeans"

libraryDependencies+="org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.1.1"

and here is my scala class:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.{KMeans, KMeansModel}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
object sparkKmeans {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
// create Spark context with Spark configuration
val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkKmeans"))      
//val threshold = args(1).toInt
// Load and parse the data. source is the first argument.
   val data = sc.textFile(args(0))    
   val parsedData = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(' ').map(_.toDouble))).cache()
    // Cluster the data into classes using KMeans. number of itteration is   fixed as 100
    // and number of clusters is get from the input -second argument
    val numClusters = args(1)
    val numIterations = 100
    val clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData, numClusters, numIterations)

    // Evaluate clustering by computing Within Set Sum of Squared Errors
    val WSSSE = clusters.computeCost(parsedData)
    println("Within Set Sum of Squared Errors = " + WSSSE)

     // Save and load model based on thirs argument.
    //clusters.save(sc, args(2))
   // val sameModel = KMeansModel.load(sc, args(2))       
  }
}
```

I have commented last two lines because I saw some places said that spark has problem with serializer. But still has the problem.

and here is the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sparkKmeans
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:174)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:689)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

and Submitting the job using:

```
 ./bin/spark-shell --class sparkKmeans ......
```

If anybody could help me I will be appreciated.

Comment: Missing `spark-mllib` dependency in build definition. Not to mention using Spark 1.1 is just crazy.  Were at 1.6 / 2.0 now.

Comment: How are you packaging your application into jar file ? and can you write down the full command after --class ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments.
I have done what you said:
Built.sbt file: 
    name:="sparkKmeans"

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %%  "spark-core" % "1.6.1",
"org.apache.spark"  % "spark-mllib_2.10" %  "1.6.1"
)
```

(I used scala 2.11.8 and Spark 1.6.1 version but still the same error.
Also about the other question:
I am packaging my application using:
sbt
compile
package

and to execute use:

```
./bin/spark-submit --class sparkKmeans k/kmeans/target/scala-2.10/sparkkmeans_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  '/home/meysam/spark-1.6.1/kmeans/pima.csv' 3
```